# External user access user lookup fields

Tags: apex, customer-community, remote-action

We have a remote action used to retrieve data and present it to external users. Among other things, we want `User` fields that are a lookup on a custom object. (`User__c` is a lookup field to User)

```
SELECT Id, User__c, User__r.Name, Active__c FROM Custom_Object__c
```

To return the value we have a wrapper object, with a constructor like this:

```
public WrapperObject(Custom_Object__c customObject){
    this.Id = customObject.Id;
    this.UserId = customObject.User__c;
    this.UserName = customObject.User__r != null ? customObject.User__r.Name : '';
    this.active = customObject.Active__c;
}
```

But here's the thing, `customObject.User__r != null` always resolves to false. It doesn't bring the drill down `Name` field on `User`.
But if I run this code as an internal user I do get the `User` field.
The code is running `with sharing` because of data security. The profile has read access to `Custom_Object__c` and all its fields.

EDIT:
After additional testing it appears that the external user cannot query any `User`.
`SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :idParam` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizational. Wide. Defaults.
The default `User` OWD setting is `Private` for External Useres. Setting it to `Public Read Only` allows the queries to return with data.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper class code will be like this:

```
public WrapperObject(Custom_Object__c customObject){
    this.Id = customObject.Id;

    Custom_Object__c obj = [SELECT Id, User__c, User__r.Name, Active__c 
                            FROM Custom_Object__c
    WHERE Id=:customObject.Id];

    this.UserId = obj.User__c;
    this.UserName = (obj.User__c != null && obj.User__r.Name !=null) ? obj.User__r.Name : '';
    this.active = customObject.Active__c;
}
```

To find the User__r.Name, you need to execute a separate SOQL query, otherwise Name will not get displayed.

Comment: That will cause null exception if no `User__r` is retrieved. The purpose of checking for null record is to make sure that I don't try to access the field of a nonexistent record or object in memory.

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem because the User__r.Name field is not being retrieved. It is being retrieved if an internal user initiates the query.

Comment: you need to run a SOQL query to retrieve User__r.Name

Comment: Like this? `SELECT Id, User__c, User__r.Name, Active__c FROM Custom_Object__c` ?

Comment: Yes, and place this code in a class mentioning `without sharing`

Comment: Please read the entire question. In detail. There you will see explained that that query is in a class `with sharing` because of security reasons. That is not an option. I need to understand why an external user cannot query a lookup user field and how to get around it.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80703/discussion-between-availablename-and-santanu-boral).